# Yii2 cannot change form response

Tags: php, yii2

So I am trying to work with an eccomerce site written in yii2, for the life of my I cannot understand how this promocode error logic works. So the cart controller has an action below in CartController.php

```
    public function actionAddPromo()
    {
        $promocode = new Promocodes();
        $insertType = $promocode->validatePromocode(Yii::$app->request->post('promo'));
        if ($insertType =="3") {
            $arr = [
                'smallcart' => $this->renderPartial('small-cart'),
                'bigcart-items' => $this->renderPartial('bigcart-items'),
                'bigcart-totals' => $this->renderPartial('bigcart-totals')
            ];
            return json_encode($arr);
        } else {
            return $insertType;
        }
    }
```

This appears to be called when a post request is sent to /cart/add-promo which occurs in this form here

```
<form action="#" id="promocode-form" method="get" class="apply-coupon">
                        <input class="search-field" id='promocode-value' data-page="cart"
                               required="required" type="text" placeholder="<?= Yii::t("app", "Coupon Code"); ?>" value=""/>
                        <input type="submit" class="button light-gray-bg " style="width:100px" value="<?= Yii::t("app", "Apply"); ?>">
                    </form>
```

The issue is that I am trying to change the error codes that come up. When the number is returned from the post request somehow "This promocode is expired" shows up but a CTRL F of the project shows no reference to this string hard coded. I have seen the modal that is modified to show up with this content but no luck in the main.php that houses it. I have inspected the onSubmit handler that is modified and sure enough it checks $trim(data) for if it is equal to 1-4 and responds with an error message. I assume this is auto-generated js by yii2/php but I cannot find the php that is responsible for creating this or where I can even look to find this.

Comment: Can't you follow the `validatePromocode` function?

Comment: I have modified it to return different numbers for different errors in another part the checkout the actionPromo function returns a literal string so I could modify the string. Validate promo just checks if it is valid and returns a number other than 3 if it is not.